# html textarea showing 'mysql text/varchar' in unformatted manner

Tags: html, cgi

Using CGI and HTML:

```
<textarea name=comments rows="6" cols="40" wrap="soft"> 
$hash_ref->{'notes'}
</textarea>
```

Mysql column has value -> 'hi there'

textarea showing as

```
 <lot of spaces before>hi there<lot of spaces after>
```

Post shows as ->

```
comments=+%0D%0A%09+hi+there+%0D%0A%09+
```

How can i get the text exactly the same as in database? Please help.

*Solution***
Funny...i changed code from:

```
 <textarea name=comments rows="6" cols="40" wrap="soft"> 
    $hash_ref->{'notes'}
    </textarea>
```

To:

```
<textarea name=comments rows="6" cols="40" wrap="soft">$hash_ref->{'notes'}</textarea>
```

And it worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use `trim()` before you echo it? It will remove leading and trailing whitespace.